# MVC3 jQuery templates

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to learn how to use jQuery templates using this old ScottGu's blog post:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/05/07/jquery-templates-and-data-linking-and-microsoft-contributing-to-jquery.aspx

And the plugin from here:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl/blob/master/jquery.tmpl.min.js

But either I'm doing something wrong, or this article isn't relevant anymore.

Could you show me a better and up-to-date one?

Comment: We can't show you what you are doing wrong if you don't post any code showing us where you are trying to implement the above techniques.

Comment: whats happening when you try?

Comment: I'm doing exactly how it described in the article. Doesn't work. Says object doesn't have .render() method

Comment: And to add on to what Chuck said below, here's an excerpt from Scott Gu's blog that you linked to, _"Because the jQuery templating proposal is still evolving in response to community feedback, the final version might look very different than the version below."_

Comment: So what's the final version then? I tried to substitute render() with tmpl() as in Chuck's sample. It didn't work either

Comment: Did you try my addition regarding making sure the jquery-tmpl file is after the jquery file in the header?

Comment: Oh... I should have passed object not an array...! Now it works... Thank you guys... case closed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote [a blog post](http://sudoit.org/2011/you-should-be-using-jquery-templates/) about jQuery templates a week or so ago. There's no special magic in getting it to work with MVC - just make sure you're returning a JSON/XML object and are referencing the correct data and it's all straightforward. You should check to make sure your templates are matching up with the data being returned by your controller method.

From your comment above it actually sounds like your issue lies in referencing the `jquery-tmpl` file before you reference the `jquery` file in your header.

Comment: your little article helped a lot... Thanks again

Comment: Chuck... one more thing. What about datalinking? What's its state now? Can I already use it? I'm asking because jQuery API documentation says about both templates and datalinking, that they are in beta stage right now.

Comment: @Agzam Not sure at all about datalinking. And yeah, you can use jQuery templates with textboxes. I've generated dynamic forms this way. It helps to identify them with a unique id if you allow the possibility for more than one to be rendered on the page.

Comment: Something like that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747426/jquery-templates-how-can-i-use-inputs

Answer (score 0):

As I found cool things that ScottGu described in that article still in beta, but you can already use them and it's cool!

here is an update snippet, that works:

```
<script type="jquery/x-jquery-tmpl" id="contactTemplate" >
  <div>
        Name: {{= name }} <br/>
        Phone: {{= phone }}
  <div>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.tmpl.min.js")" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var contact = { name: 'Scott Guthrie', phone: '31415' };

    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $('#contactTemplate').tmpl(contact).appendTo('#contactContainer');
    });
</script>
```

As you can see .render() method changed to .tmpl() and instead of an array I'm passing a single object.