# jQuery templates, how can I use inputs?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-templates

After [this conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746783/mvc3-jquery-templates) I started wondering if it's possible to use that and apply to textboxes. I want something like that:

```
<script type="jquery/x-jquery-tmpl" id="contactTemplate" >
<div>
    <input type="text" value= {{ = name }}  />
    <input type="text" value= {{ = phone }}  />
<div>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var contacts = { name: 'Scott Guthrie', phone: '31415' };

   $(document).ready(function() 
  {
      $('#contactTemplate').tmpl(contacts).appendTo('#contactContainer');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure thing:

```
<script type="jquery/x-jquery-tmpl" id="contactTemplate" >
    <div>
        <input type="text" value="${name}"  />
        <input type="text" value="${phone}"  />
        <div>
</script>
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ca35T/

Comment: I found out the answer momentarily after I posted the question. Gosh, stackoverflow makes me lazy. I don't wanna look anymore in the documentation. it's easier to post a question here

Comment: @Agzam: Haha, I hear ya. No worries!

Comment: @Agzam was it sarcastic? IMVHO not a good move to get rid of documentation.

Comment: @Whitaker Yeah the thing is, you posted answer so quick. It's like entire stackoverflow society's competition against google's instant search

Comment: @Guandalino... yeah I thought "bazzinga" implicitly implied here